# Filing Sales Tax Return When 3rd Party Collects & Remits Sales Tax - App Store & Google Play Scenario, US

Tags: united-states, new-york, sales-tax, google

In many cases App Store & Google Play will collect & remit sales tax themselves for your sales.

Question is how to file this scenario. Do you file these sales as "non taxable sales" or do you file a $0 sales tax return?

This question is for US, New York.

Comment: @PeterCooperJr. added.

Comment: Assuming "NYS" means "New York State", I've added the [tag:new-york] tag for you.